# No instruction in main function when debugging with winedbg

Tags: radare2

I'v try to debugging windows PE file under Linux.

```
winedbg --gdb --no-start a.exe                                                  ─╯
00bc:00c0: create process 'Z:\home\coolder\a.exe'/0x1106b8 @0x4014c0 (83456<1315>)
00bc:00c0: create thread I @0x4014c0
target remote localhost:59889
```

And use radare2 to connect to it.

```
r2 -e dbg.exe.path=./a.exe -d gdb://localhost:59889                             ─╯
= attach 192 1
= attach 192 0
WARNING: (dwarf_process.c:902):map_dwarf_reg_to_x86_reg: code should not be reached
 -- Don't wait for Travis
[0x0061fefc]>
```

```
[0x000015e0]> pd 3
            ;-- main:
            ;-- _main:
            0x000015e0      ff             invalid
            0x000015e1      ff             invalid
            0x000015e2      ff             invalid
```

Why there's nothing in main funtion?

I have used 'aaa' to analyze.

But when I use 'dc', the program runs correctly.

How to fix it?

Comment: It's been a while but I seem to recall windows programs don't typically have a main() rather they're an event loop called by the OS.  Try looking at an example of how to make one; even better, build it and reverse engineer that.

Comment: I can see main function and instructions in main in IDA, I can't see it only when using winedbg and r2, maybe it's a bug.